# Roots of real polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I do not know how to deal with this problem:

Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be a polynomial such that for some points $(a,b) , (c,d)$ we have $f(a,b) > 0 > f(c,d)$. Show that $f$ has an infinite number of roots.

Answer (score 4):

(answer to the original question)

The polynomial $(x-y)^2$ is always nonnegative but it has infinitely many zeroes.

(answer to the edited, reversed question)

This is actually true for any continuous real function in multiple real variables. In fact by continuity there has to be a zero on any continuous path from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ and there are infinitely many such paths that do not intersect outside the terminating points.